# How to activate urban airship

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

Thanks for previous replies.

I am trying to integrate urban airship into my application. for this i registries in urbanairship website and got some credentials, also i got sample program to test the application. even the application is working, but sent item from the urban air website is not display in notification. dont know how to implement urban airship. can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi, can u tel me what have you implemented till now in your code

Comment: actually i am new to urban airship. i got samples from airship website, and integrated my own credentials.

Comment: here is a step by step tutorial on how to achieve this <http://life-optimized.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-push-notifications-using-urban.html>

Comment: HARIRAM@ Did you complete this functionality i am troubling with the same situation. First of all i am prity confused with productionaapkey and secret. Why it is required in Sample application. What i need to put here. A test notification is not arriving at all. Urban Airship is totally bad documentation at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Have you added this code ??**

```
 AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this);
    options.developmentAppKey = "Your Development AppKey";
    options.developmentAppSecret ="Your development AppSecret";
    options.productionAppKey = "Your production app key";
    options.inProduction = false;   //   determines which app key to use

    UAirship.takeOff(this, options);
    Logger.logLevel = Log.VERBOSE;

    //  use CustomPushNotificationBuilder to specify a custom layout
    CustomPushNotificationBuilder nb = new CustomPushNotificationBuilder();
    nb.statusBarIconDrawableId = R.drawable.icon;   //  custom statusbar icon
    nb.layout = R.layout.notification;
    nb.layoutIconDrawableId = R.drawable.notifyicon;    //  custom layout icon
    nb.layoutIconId = R.id.icon;
    nb.layoutSubjectId = R.id.subject;
    nb.layoutMessageId = R.id.message;

    PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(nb);
    PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
```

***Add below code to your menifest and try it, you have to add this for sure***

```
<!--  Urban AirShip  -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<!-- REQUIRED for C2DM  -->
<!--
    Only this application can receive the messages and registration result
-->
<!--
    MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Replace "com.urbanairship.push.sample" with
    your package name
-->
<permission android:name="com.urbanairship.pushdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.urbanairship.pushdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- End Urban AirShip -->
```

Comment: Yes, but i dint give production app key. where can i get perfect example for this.

Comment: its not needed and i haven't added it in my code too, have you added code properly in your manifest file ?

Comment: This is sample from urban airship, there is no need to add anything in manifest file. what should we add new to this file..??

Comment: do you have any samples for this ..??

Comment: have you added the package name properly at urbanairship site ??

Comment: yes added correct package name in website.. dont know where i made mistake.